# NameError is not defined with Json and Pandas in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nameerror

Trying to extract specific lines after string from a JSON file, append data in JSON format then send to to Dataframe, this was working but not now. Anyone know why I'm now getting a NameError?

*z = json.loads(line)
NameError: name 'line' is not defined*

```
import fileinput, re, json
import pandas as pd

p = [
    "Test/a",
    "Test/b"
]
dir = "/home/****/"

for i,ip in enumerate(p):
    t = ip.replace('/', '')
    directory = dir + t
    found = False
    for line in fileinput.input(directory + "/" + t +"_type.json",inplace=True):
       if re.match('{"p',line):
           found = True
        if found:
           print(line,end="")

   y = {"p":"example"}

   z = json.loads(line)

   z.update(y)

   q = json.dumps(z)

   df = pd.read_json(q)
   for i, g in df.groupby([
      "Apple",
      "Bannana"
       ]):
       print(g)
```

Comment: You need to indent the line `z = json.loads(line)`
Notice how it is out of scope of the for-loop

Comment: Thanks, yep it was the indent of all but the 'for i, g in df.groupby([' , don't know why it changed but its appears to be working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your `for` loop takes each item from `fileinput.input(directory + "/" + t +"_type.json",inplace=True)` and places it into the variable `line`. However this variable is only defined in your `for` loop so as soon as the program leaves the loop, it is not defined anymore. 
You have a couple of solutions depending on how you want your program to behave, but they all work pretty much the same, you just have to choose what you want to execute and when :

```py
for i,ip in enumerate(p):
    t = ip.replace('/', '')
    directory = dir + t
    found = False
    for line in fileinput.input(directory + "/" + t +"_type.json",inplace=True):
        if re.match('{"p',line):
            found = True
        if found:
            print(line,end="")

            # From there we add 2 levels of indentation in order to execute
            # the code if found is true

            y = {"p":"example"}

            z = json.loads(line)

            z.update(y)

            q = json.dumps(z)

            df = pd.read_json(q)
            for i, g in df.groupby([
               "Apple",
               "Bannana"
                ]):
                print(g)
```

or

```py
for i,ip in enumerate(p):
    t = ip.replace('/', '')
    directory = dir + t
    found = False
    for line in fileinput.input(directory + "/" + t +"_type.json",inplace=True):
        if re.match('{"p',line):
            found = True
        if found:
            print(line,end="")

        # From there we add 1 levels of indentation in order to execute
        # the code for each iteration of the loop

        y = {"p":"example"}

        z = json.loads(line)

        z.update(y)
        q = json.dumps(z)

        df = pd.read_json(q)
        for i, g in df.groupby([
            "Apple",
            "Bannana"
             ]):
             print(g)
```

I hope you will find this helpful